# How to use a user input in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Side note, I'm new to python3 and don't know the correct term for what something like `df.Id` would be called.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("desktop/python/test.csv")

column_name = input('column name ')
column_name1 = ("df." + column_name)
print(df.column_name)
```

My goal is to have the user input which column they want to see which will go into the df. function and print the column.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("desktop/python/test.csv")

column_name = input('column name ')

print(df[column_name])
```